# In a CakePHP IntegrationTest "Redis"-class is unknown only when executing the test

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I am trying to implement an PHPUnit integration-test for a Controller. Within the controller I instantiate an Object of the PHPRedis-class (https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#usage):

`//connect to redis database
    try 
    {
        $this->objPHPRedis = new \Redis();
        $this->objPHPRedis->connect('127.0.0.1');
    } 
    catch(\RedisException $e) 
    {
        $this->log($e, 1);
    } 
        catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $this->log($e, 1);
    }`

This works great when I process normal requests, but it fails when I execute the test:

`PHP Fatal error: Class Redis not found in /var/www/.../MyController.php on line 100.`

I have no idea where to start searching for the problem. Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CLI config for php has the redis module not loaded. Find your CLI php.ini, probably named `cli_php.ini` or something similar and make sure your redis module is loaded there as well.